# Is there is any difference between `std::list` and boost library `boost::ptr_list` in c++?

Tags: c++, boost

Is there any difference in the <strike>STL</strike> Standard Library provided `std::list` and Boost Library provided `boost::ptr_list` ?

Comment: This is a question you can probably answer: Does their respective documentation outline any? The STL is long dead, too, it's now just the [Standard Library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header).

Comment: One owns the object in it, the other doesn't. There's also smart pointers to think about...

Comment: @RetiredNinja Both maintain ownership. std::list makes a copy (or moves the object) that it owns `boost::ptr_list` takes ownership of the pointer (thus deletes it). Neither provide a leaky abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the `boost::ptr_list` [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_list.html), it says:

> A `ptr_list<T>` is a pointer container that uses an underlying `std:list<void*>` to store the pointers.
>
> It should also be noted that `boost:ptr_list` like `std::list` own the object it contains. So `ptr_list` will call delete on the pointer at some point.

That said, the interface is very similar:

- `ptr_list` API has `push_front(T*)`, `push_front(appropriate-smart-pointer-type<U> p)` and also inherits from [`ptr-sequence-adapter`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_sequence_adapter.html) to provide further functionality.
- the `std::list<>` provides a slightly more modern interface that includes move semantics but is otherwise identical - see [cppreference docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list)